# add a bmp to picture control using win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to load a .bmp file into a picture control. The bitmap IDB_BITMAP1 was added using the Resource View of Visual Studio. The picture control has id IDC_THUMBNAIL.

The following code doesn't work

```
HBITMAP hBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));

[...]

case WM_INITDIALOG:
{

[...]

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_THUMBNAIL), STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBMP);
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: The static control must have the `SS_BITMAP` style. Otherwise, this code works fine...

Comment: i modified the style using the VS interface, now the .rc file shows: CONTROL "",IDC_THUMBNAIL,"Static",SS_BITMAP,479,108,15,13

Comment: FYI, this is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782.aspx): "*To associate an image with a static control, the control must have the proper style. The following table shows the style needed for each image... `IMAGE_BITMAP` - `SS_BITMAP`*"